# Codeigniter - Join same table and search with array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, join

I have two input fields. Both leading to an array array of colors that will be matched on the database. 
The arrays can look like this

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => blue [2] => green )
```

One input is used for searching a table called ´image_topcolor´ and the other input is searching another table, ´image_bottomcolor´.

I'm trying to come up with a structure to search for images with these two inputs based on color selection.

I want the user to be able to select several colors and then return all images which has the selected color in the database.
The search works fine when using only one input field with the following code:

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('image');

if(!empty($top_colors[0]) && empty($bottom_colors[0])) {
$this->db->join('image_topcolor', 'image_topcolor.image_id = image.id' ,'inner');
$this->db->join('color', 'color.id = image_topcolor.color_id', 'inner');
}
if(!empty($bottom_colors[0]) && empty($top_colors[0])) {    
$this->db->join('image_bottomcolor', 'image_bottomcolor.image_id = image.id' ,'inner'); 
$this->db->join('color', 'color.id = image_bottomcolor.color_id', 'inner');
}

if(!empty($bottom_colors[0])) {     
$this->db->where_in('color', $bottom_colors); 
}
if(!empty($top_colors[0])) {
$this->db->where_in('color', $top_colors); 
}
```

This returns images to the user even if the user has selected a color that doesn't have an id matched with an image yet, which is perfect! 

I want this to work the same way when using both input fields to find all images that matches the colors from the inputs.

I want to use something similiar to:

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('image');

if(!empty($top_colors[0]) && !empty($bottom_colors[0])) {
$this->db->join('image_topcolor', 'image_topcolor.image_id = image.id' ,'left');
$this->db->join('image_bottomcolor', 'image_bottomcolor.image_id = image.id' ,'left');      
$this->db->join('color as a', 'image_topcolor.color_id = a.id','left');
$this->db->join('color as b', 'image_bottomcolor.color_id = b.id','left');
}

if(!empty($top_colors[0]) && !empty($bottom_colors[0])) {
$this->db->where_in('a', $top_colors); 
$this->db->where_in('b', $bottom_colors); 
}
```

This returns with the error

> "Column 'color' in where clause is ambiguous"

"SELECT * FROM `image` LEFT JOIN `image_topcolor` ON `image_topcolor`.`image_id` = `image`.`id` LEFT JOIN `image_bottomcolor` ON `image_bottomcolor`.`image_id` = `image`.`id` LEFT JOIN `color` as `a` ON `image_topcolor`.`color_id` = `a`.`id` LEFT JOIN `color` as `b` ON `image_bottomcolor`.`color_id` = `b`.`id` WHERE `color` IN('blue') AND `color` IN('red') AND `a`.`color` IN('red') AND `b`.`color` IN('blue')"

I'm not sure how I can use both arrays to find all images that matches any of the selected colors.
My tables looks like this: 
**image**

```
id | color | info
---|-------|------
1  | blue  | foo
2  | red   | bar
```

**color**

```
id | color |
---|-------|
1  | red   |
2  | blue  | 
3  | green |
```

**image_topcolor**

```
image_id | color_id |
---------|----------|
1        | 1        |
1        | 2        |
```

**image_bottomcolor**

```
image_id | color_id |
---------|----------|
2        | 1        |
2        | 3        |
```

Sorry for the long post.
Question recap:
How can I get the results of **all** images with matching colors when using both inputs? Just like I get when using only one input. 
 
Thanks!

**Update**
This query is now not generating any errors.
But I'm still not getting the results if the user selects a color that doesn't exist. I only get the result if the image has the same selected color in both tables.
Example: An image has red, blue top_color and blue, green bottom color. I cannot get this result by searching for red top and green bottom. However if I search for blue top and blue bottom, I get the result. I guess this has do with the joins?

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('image');
    if(!empty($top_colors[0]) && !empty($bottom_colors[0])) {
    $this->db->join('image_topcolor', 'image_topcolor.image_id = image.id' ,'left');
    $this->db->join('image_bottomcolor', 'image_bottomcolor.image_id = image.id' ,'left');  


$this->db->join('color as a', 'image_topcolor.color_id = a.id','left');
$this->db->join('color as b', 'image_bottomcolor.color_id = b.id','left');

if(!empty($top_colors[0]) && !empty($bottom_colors[0])) {
$result = array_merge($top_colors, $bottom_colors);

$this->db->where_in('a.color', $top_colors); 
$this->db->where_in('b.color', $bottom_colors);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not use the where_in syntax correct. You need to use the name of the field as the first argument of the function, not the table name (alias).

Try this:

```
if(!empty($top_colors[0]) && !empty($bottom_colors[0])) {
$this->db->where_in('a.color', $top_colors); 
$this->db->where_in('b.color', $bottom_colors); 
}
```

UPDATE:
To get your desired result you should also use or_where_in, like this:

```
if(!empty($top_colors[0]) && !empty($bottom_colors[0])) {
  $this->db->where_in('a.color', $top_colors);
  $this->db->or_where_in('b.color', $bottom_colors); 
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the "Column 'color' in where clause is ambiguous" error, I'll edit more info the post

Comment: Could there be an other place you have a where condition? The error message clearly tells about where condition. Could you please paste your generated sql statement?

Comment: I've added the generated sql

Comment: It seems to me you have some other conditions somewhere left in your code. Are you sure you removed the piece of code form you first try? `if(!empty($bottom_colors[0])) {     
$this->db->where_in('color', $bottom_colors); 
}
if(!empty($top_colors[0])) {
$this->db->where_in('color', $top_colors); 
}`

Comment: I appreciate the help! I added an update to the bottom of the post

Comment: @NoIndexFound I have updated my answer. Hope I did not misunderstood your request.

Comment: This might actually be working! I will try this out for a bit and maybe tweak some with it.  I'm marking this as resolved! Thanks a ton for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you joined the same table twice, the two tables have exactly the same set of fields. Therefore, every time you reference a field from one of these two tables, you need to prefix the field name with the table alias, such as `a.color`.

I believe in codeigniter you can achieve this in the following way:

```
...
$this->db->where_in('a.color', $top_colors); 
$this->db->where_in('b.color', $bottom_colors);
...
```

Comment: Alright! One step closer. I'm still getting the "Column 'color' in where clause is ambiguous" error though. My select looks like this "$this->db->select('*'); "  Should I write the specific color aliases in the select as well?

Comment: With select * there is no need to specify table aliases for individual columns, although it may be a trifle difficult to distinguish between the fields of the 2 tables without field aliases on the client side. Do you have any other where criteria that use the color field? Can you pls paste the generated sql in the question above?

Comment: I've added the generated sql

Comment: As was pointed out by moni_dragu: you must have some other code left interfering with your current code. You may have to use fluch_cache() or reset() methods on your query builder to remove any criteria from a previous query you executed.

Comment: The sql is now working without giving me the error. But I'm still not getting the results I wanted. As I mentioned when using only one input, I get the image even if the user selected a color that doesn't match. This doesn't seem to work with two inputs. I added an update at the bottom. Thanks a ton for helping (: